# axios not sending request body in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, post, axios

I'm trying to send a POST request using axios from NodeJS, but the body/data of the request is not sent.

I am using axios and NodeJS on the back end, and this is my NodeJS script which sends the request:

```js
const axios = require("axios").default;

axios.post("my url goes here/email.php", {
   emailto: "receiver email",
    toname: "name",
    emailfrom: "sender email",
    fromname: "name",
    subject: "subject",
    messagebody: "hello world"
});
```

When the receiving server tries to read the data in the request (eg by declaring $subject = $_POST[subject]; in PHP), the parameters of the request are `null` - so `$_POST[subject]` returns `null`.

However, when I send the same request using not axios but jQuery (on the front end), it works perfectly in that the receiving server can now read the data of the POST request (so `$_POST[subject]` this time returns "subject"):

```js
$.ajax("https://my url goes here/email.php", {
  method: "POST",
  cache: false,
  data: {
        emailto: "receiver's email",
        toname: "name",
        emailfrom: "sender email",
        fromname: "name",
        subject: "subject",
        messagebody: "hello world"
    }
})
```

When I run the second snippet, on the PHP-server `$_POST[subject]` returns "subject", but when I run the first snippet in NodeJS, `$_POST[subject]` returns `null`. Why is axios not sending my request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format):

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON

So you are POSTing JSON to the server.

PHP doesn't support JSON when it comes to populating `$_POST`.

You need to POST a format that it supports, such as URL Encoded Form Data or Multipart Form Data.

(Your jQuery example is using URL Encoded Form Data).

> To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead,
> you can use the URLSearchParams API, which is supported in the vast
> majority of browsers, and Node starting with v10 (released in 2018).
>
> ```
> const params = new URLSearchParams({ foo: 'bar' });
> params.append('extraparam', 'value');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you. I ended up using the URLSearchParams' .toString method to turn them into a query string and POST them that way, and I can now deliver emails.

Answer (score -1):

add a content body such as `{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` to the request but I would edit this and

```
const axios = require("axios");

var data = JSON.stringify({ 
        emailto: "receiver email",
        toname: "name",
        emailfrom: "sender email",
        fromname: "name",
        subject: "subject",
        messagebody: "hello world"
        });

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://alpha-howl.com/database/email.php',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};


try { 
    await axios(config)
} catch (ex) { 
throw ex
}
```

Mainly to make sure you are resolving the promise that is returned by axios to make sure the request is even successful.

Comment: The **problem** is that Axios is POSTing JSON. Your proposed solution is just to recreate the problem but doing a bunch of work  yourself that Axios was already doing automatically in the OP's example.

Comment: Clearly you didnt review the code above, as I am not posting json but a json string, see where I am using JSON.stringify My proposed solution worked. As it was tested. As well, simple error catching in the resolved promise of thecode, would have given the context needed for you to fix this issue, without the need for this question to even be posted. @Quentin

Comment: "Clearly you didnt review the code above" — I did.

Comment: "as I am not posting json but a json string, see where I am using JSON.stringify" — In JavaScript you have a string containing JSON. In the HTTP request you have a request body containing JSON (but it is not a string because HTTP request bodies aren't programming languages which have a concept of "a string"). You just don't understand the correct terminology properly. As I said, axios will run an object through `JSON.stringify` automatically. You've just moved the step that does that out of axios and into your own code … which is a pointless waste of effort.

Comment: "As well, simple error catching in the resolved promise of thecode, would have given the context needed for you to fix this issue" — It doesn't, since the problem the OP has doesn't cause PHP to do anything that would make axios throw an exception.

Comment: "would have given the context needed for you to fix this issue, without the need for this question to even be posted" — It's not my problem, and I didn't need to add any error handling to determine what the OP's problem was.

Comment: "My proposed solution worked" — No, it didn't. As I said, it is a pointless exercise in deckchair rearrangement. It hasn't changed anything about what the code does.